# How to combine local mailboxes and imap ones in mutt?

Tags: email, imap, mutt, neomutt

I used to read my email with neomutt and get them from server with fetchmail. For a time, I switched to using mostly my webmail, but now I'd like to combine mail archives managed by mutt and continuing to use webmail.

This could be achieved in several ways I'm sure, what I think more convenient for me is to use imap mailboxes side by side with local ones in mutt.

I find examples of imap-only muttrc files, but I am not sure how to configure mutt to have both local and imap ones. The most confusing is that there seems to be one `$folder` variable only, and that depending on whether the mailbox is local or imap, this variable should be set do `~/Maildir` or to `imaps://host`.

So, how do I configure `mutt` to still have `~/Maildir/Inbox` as my spoolfile and `imaps://host/Inbox` as an additional mailbox?

Answer (score 2):

You can use two $folder variables in your .muttrc:

```
set folder = imaps://some@email.com@some.server.com:993  
set spoolfile = "=INBOX"  
mailboxes =INBOX  
set folder = "~/Mail"
```

The first 'set folder' sets the imap folder and the variable to use with 'set spoolfile' and 'mailboxes'. Afterwards, a second 'set folder' changes the variable to your local mail folders. In mutt, changing folder to local ~/Mail is by 'c?' or 'y<kbd>tab</kbd>'. In neomutt, sometimes you have to use 'c?<kbd>tab</kbd>=' or 'y<kbd>tab</kbd>='. You can change back to your imap inbox with 'y'.

I copied this from someone's muttrc posted online a long time ago. This works for me and allows my webmail inbox or gmail to work together with my local mail folders.

Hope this helps,
ErwinKKK